# How to connect to login page on paid wifi services?

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, internet-connection

In hotels and many other places they offer WiFi as a paid service. The network is open, but when you connect you will be redirected to a page where you pay for internet access, or enter a code.

On many networks now at various hotels across the USA I am able to connect successfully and load the redirect page on a Windows 7 computer, an iPad, and an Android. But on my Surface Pro 4 I can connect but it will not load the redirect page. It automatically opens a tab in my default browser and attempts to load a page at go.microsoft.com, but it just hangs there forever. It has loaded the redirect successfully a few times, but only after 10 to 20 minutes of waiting and a lot of cursing.

I've tried different browsers and even typing the URL to the redirect page, as it appears on a different device.

Is there some trick I can do to learn the redirect page and force it to load? Is there some kind of protocol I can do to get a diagnosis of the problem? I only have the one Windows 10 device, so maybe there is a setting I am unaware of that is blocking the redirect.

Comment: Try going to http://neverssl.com/ first

Comment: @DavidPostill I've tried http sites, rather than https, many times, and it hasn't worked, but I'll try this specific one.

Answer (score 1):

We have two possibilities here. Your browser/Windows is caching the DNS or it's configured to use a static DNS server.

First check your IPv4 config on your network adapter. See [how to config IPv4](https://idoc.vsb.cz/xwiki/bin/view/tuonet/sit-nastaveni/tcp-ip/tcp-ip-win10/?language=en). It must be configured to "automatically".

Force your windows to flush the DNS cache:

1. Open `cmd` as Administrator.
2. Type `ipconfig /flushdns`, press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
3. Disconnect and connect again.
4. Open a browser and try to open `google.com`.

You must be redirected to the authentication/login.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. At the time, I believe I tried both of these in several ways. Currently, the issue no longer exists. I blame a bad Win 10 update.

Comment: I am currently having this problem and that isn't fixing it. No clue what to do next.

Comment: Hi @PeteMancini try to open a site you never opened before. like google in a different country .it .ca .com.br ....

Comment: @alexrgs thanks. Figured it out. Popups were blocked.